# Drop Down List populated from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a drop down list and the values I get them from SQL.

There are 4 choices. I need on one of the choices to turn a `textbox.visible = false;`

I am not sure that is correct. I have it in SQL as Cancel_Reason

```
protected void ddlCancelReason_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Item = ddlCancelReason.SelectedValue;

    if (Item == "Non-Payment")
    {
        tbReturn.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Is this WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: It doesn't do it. The textbox is still there.

Comment: The application runs without any error

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  What is the selected _text_ value of the selected item?  Does it even enter the if statement?

Comment: In SQL the ID = 2. Should I change it to 2?

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on the `if` statement look at what the value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you bind a `SelectedIndexChanged` event to your `DropDownList`? If you did:

In your case it won't work because you didn't **enable** the `AutoPostBack`-property of the `DropDownList`.

Change your `DropDownList` code from:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCancelReason" runat="server" datatextfield="Cancel_Reason" datavaluefield="ID"> </asp:dropdownlist>
```

To:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCancelReason" AutoPostback="true" runat="server" datatextfield="Cancel_Reason" datavaluefield="ID"> </asp:dropdownlist>
```

Just add `AutoPostback="true"`.

Then this will work:

```
protected void ddlCancelReason_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Item = ddlCancelReason.SelectedValue;

    if (Item == "Non-Payment")
    {
        tbReturn.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't do it.

Comment: This maybe can help you more:

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCancelReason" runat="server" DataTextField="Cancel_Reason"
                    DataValueField="ID">
                </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Yes. The second one it tells "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @user3508633 can you show the code in your Page_Load?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Item = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
       
        if (SessionConstants.facility == "0")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        if (Item == "Non-Payment")
        {
            tbReturn.Visible = false;
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillDropDowns();
            GetData();
            
        }

    }

Comment: @TheOddGuy - change your answer to use the drop down changed event.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks, that's a better solution indeed.

Comment: You are checking for if (Item =="Non-Payment") in your page_load event, and this will not have any value stored in your Item variable, and hence, the textbox doesn't become visible. Your ddlCancelReason_SelectedIndexChanged Event should work with the code given above.. !!